# What Does This Mean and How Does It Help?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

At the moment I'm coding a web application that imports image data from Google Maps via the Static API - http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/ - into an HTML5 canvas.

Unfortunately, I've run into the problem of not being able to manipulate the pixel data from Google Maps due to cross domain restrictions.

However, I've been reading this blog post by Mr. Doob, one of the people behind the Wilderness Downtown video ( http://thewildernessdowntown.com ) which employs canvas with Google Maps - http://mrdoob.com/blog/post/705 - and it reads:

> "An additional challenge was that with  you don't have access to the pixel data of images loaded from another domain...However, albeit pixel access is forbidden, context.drawImage() is allowed for copying areas from images hosted on other domains."

I feel this may be the solution to my problem as later in the post it shows pixel manipulation of the image, but I don't quite get what exactly it means by 'context.drawImage() is allowed for copying areas from images hosted on other domains' and it would be really helpful if someone could clarify it for me.

Thanks,

DLiKS

Edit: Here is the code I'm using to draw the Google Maps image to the canvas:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d'); 
var img = new Image(); 
img.src = 'LINK TO GOOGLE MAPS IMAGE'; 
img.onload = function(){ 
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0); 
}
```

The image displays OK but when I try to use getImageData to manipulate this embedded image on the canvas, I get a security error

Comment: Interesting question, +1. As a side note, be aware that Google's Maps are copyright protected material, so there are certain limitations on what you can legally do with them.

Comment: `Unfortunately, I've run into the problem of not being able to manipulate the pixel data from Google Maps due to cross domain restrictions.` What code do you use?

Comment: I've added the code as an edit into the question.

Comment: Nice question, I don't get it neither. I tried to copy the the image data from one canvas element to another, but manipulating the second canvas gives a security error too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having read the article I think you misinterpreted what Mr.doob said:

> *"[Jamie] then started researching other ways of **drawing** the Maps Data in a way that would create the same effect."*

He does **no pixel manipulation**, he uses `context.drawImage` for

> *"...**cropping** columns from the original image and **positioning** them one after the other horizontally."*

Comment: How is this possible... Really! I was JUST about to give EXACTLY the same answer, but you've beaten me in an incredible 13 seconds!

Answer (score 2):

Assign `src` to image using one aspx page, and that aspx page will respond with your text to the image.

For example:

```
image.src="CreateImage.aspx";
image.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(image,5,5,width,height);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`context.drawImage()` i believe is some way of manipulating a HTML 5 Canvas. 
Take a look at these webpages.

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html-5-canvas-the-basics/
http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/canvas.html

Comment: heh. I was half-way through posting a near-identical answer. No point now, so I'll just add my weight to yours (can't +1 as I've run out of votes for the day)

Comment: context.drawImage() is just the standard way of placing an image onto the canvas. However, just using it as in the linked examples doesn't allow for pixel based image manipulation of remote images (which is what I'm trying to achieve). What I'm trying to figure out is how Mr. Doob has managed to get around this restriction via some clever manipulation of this function. Thanks for the answer though!

Comment: Indeed, this is not an answer to the question. I tried to use `drawImage` but it gives an exception: `SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18`